# Sagemaker Studio Associate Notebook with Running App

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am running Sagemaker Studio and have per the picture below, a running instance of a specific instance type. This was created when i created a new notebook and picked the instance type and kernel. But that creation also ended with an error message I exceeded the quota for that type. It seems to be running though, how to actually use it for a notebook?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an app running on that instance, so if you open a notebook and select the ml.g4dn.xlarge instance and the pytorch-1.12-gpu optimized image, you will be able to use this. You can also create more notebooks with different images using the same instance.